# Как сделать url с двумя slug?

Tags: python, django

Как сделать url для товара со своим слагом, и с слагом категории. Например: category/slug категории/slug товара/

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wishlist = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user.username)


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155, verbose_name='Название категории')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/category', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Картинка категории')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='Слаг категории')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155, verbose_name='Название товара')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание товара')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, verbose_name='Цена')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/product/%m', verbose_name='Картинка товара')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='Адрес товара')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
models.py

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155, verbose_name='Название категории')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/category', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Картинка категории')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='Слаг категории')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155, verbose_name='Название товара')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание товара')
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Цена')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/product/%m', verbose_name='Картинка товара')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='Адрес товара')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . views import *


urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('register/', user_register, name='register'),
    path('logout/', user_logout, name='logout'),
    path('login/', user_login, name='login'),
    path('<str:slug>/', CategoryList.as_view(), name='category'),
    path('<str:category__slug>/<str:slug>/', ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product'),
]
```

```
views.py

class CategoryList(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'categories.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'
    paginate_by = 10
    allow_empty = False

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = Category.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return context


class ProductDetail(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'
```

Answer (score 0):

Части url по шаблону попадают в `self.kwargs` `class base view` объекта

```
class ProductDetail(...):

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return Product.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'), category__slug=self.kwargs.get('category__slug'))
        except Product.DoesNotExists:
            raise Http404
```

---

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('register/', user_register, name='register'),
    path('logout/', user_logout, name='logout'),
    path('login/', user_login, name='login'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', CategoryList.as_view(), name='category'),
    path('<slug:category__slug>/<slug:slug>/', ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product'),
]
```

Comment: Мне выдает ошибку: NoReverseMatch at /category/mac/
Reverse for 'product' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'macbookpro'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P<category__slug>[^/]+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: в примере опечатка была, исправил. `get_objects` => `get_object`

Comment: почему-то все равно ошибка возникает при переходе в категорию: NoReverseMatch at /category/mac/

Comment: это проблема с CalegotyList. Ща посмотрю. кстати поменяйте <str:slug> на <slug:slug> и в остальных местах где str для SlugField

Comment: Откуда у вас ` ['product/(?P<category__slug>[^/]+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']` . Приведите код в вопросе в актуальное состояние

Comment: Я обновил код в urls.py

Comment: проверьте что у вас есть товар и он в нужной категории, и обновите `get_absolute_urls` товара в соответсвии с `urls.py`

Comment: Все вроде бы нормально, но ошибка все равно появляется. Обновлю вопрос и добавлю models.py

Comment: поменяйте везде тип в урлах на `slug`,

Comment: Все равно вылезает эта ошибка. Я даже на страницу категории зайти не могу. Проблема , я так понимаю, в get_absolute_url:         return reverse('product', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

Comment: и тут тоже, у, добавьте "category__slug": self.category.slug